# How to call second method only after first method returns observable?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, methods, rxjs, observable

```
buttonClicked() {
    let num = 0;
    this.myService.myFirstMethod().subscribe(response=> {
        num = response.result;
    });

    this.myService.mySecondMethod(num).subscribe(response=> {
        console.log(response);
    });        
}
```

How can I call the second method only when the first one is returned, chain them like `.then` in Promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map an observable emission to another observable by using a "[Higher order mapping operator](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" (`switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `exhaustMap`).

If your `myFirstMethod()` only emits a single value, it doesn't really matter which one you use, let's us `switchMap`, for this example:

```js
buttonClicked() {
    this.myService.myFirstMethod().pipe(
        switchMap(num => this.myService.mySecondMethod(num))
    ).subscribe(secondResponse => {
        console.log(secondResponse);
    });        
}
```

You pass a function that returns an observable to `switchMap`. This "*inner observable*" will be subscribed (*and unsubscribed*) to internally by switchMap. Emissions from the "inner observable" are then emitted.  So, it essentially maps an emission from observable #1 to emissions from observable #2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switchMap`

```js
buttonClicked() {
    this.myService
        .myFirstMethod()
        .pipe(switchMap(response => {
           const num = response.result;
           return this.myService.mySecondMethod(num)
        }))
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });        
}
```